# How to trigger JQuery action without breaking separation of concerns

Tags: jquery, ember.js, semantic-ui

I use SemanticUI and Ember and I would like to make some content disappear with a transition when clicking a button.

The way to do this with SemanticUI is to call `$('#id').transition('type-of-transition')` with `id` being the ID of the element you want to make disappear.

### Partial solutions

#### Putting this code in the controller

I could create an action in the controller that calls `$('#id').transition('type-of-transition')`. The problem is that the controller shoud not be aware of the view(s).

#### Using the `<script>` tag

I could use the plain old way of doing this (setting an event with JQuery or in plain JS), but it does not seem to be the "Ember way" of doing things.

#### Create a generic "transition-element" component

I could create a component like:

```
{{#transition-component shouldHide=shouldHide}}
<!-- Here comes what I want to make disappear -->
{{/transition-component}}
```

And observe the property `shouldHide` to launch the transition when is toggles to `true`. The problem is that Ember refreshes the DOM, so view will disappear, but then reappear.

Any solution?

Comment: What sort of transition are you looking to do?  Are you just looking to fade the component in?

Comment: Speaking in terms of SemanticUI's transition, I want to do a `fade down` transition for now, but I want to be able to do different transitions in the future. Does that change something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `didInsertElement` on your component to specify a transition.  For example, have a property on your controller that we can toggle:

```
testBoolean: false;
```

Then an action:

```
  actions: {
    toggleBool() {
      set(this, 'testBool', !get(this, 'testBool'));
    }
  }
```

Have your component wrapped in an if:

```
{{#if testBool}}
  {{test-component}}
{{/if}}
<button {{action toggleBool on="click"}}>Click</button>
```

Then on your component, specify the transition you want:

```
  didInsertElement: function(){
    this.$().hide().show('slow');
  }
```

Or whatever jquery transition you want.  So, the component will be toggled by clicking the button, and when it is inserted, it should call `didInsertElement` each time.  (I'm not familiar with SumanticUI, personally, but I have to do stuff like this in Ember all the time).

Comment: Souds a bit like a hack, but it works. Anyway I now use liquid fire to perform transitions. I mark your answer as accepted